# How is memory being used during a, b = 1, 2?

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I was curious to find whether:

```
a = 0
a, a = a + 1, a + 1
print(a)
```

would print 1 or 2. The output was 1, but I can't really explain why was that. How does memory work in such example?

Comment: Question title doesn't match code...

Comment: the tuple `(a+1, a+1)` is computed as `(1,1)` then it assigned each of those to the variables specified, so it assigns `a` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each assignment is individually evaluated, not sequentially because the right hand side is evaluated first as a tuple, then unpacked

As far as memory goes, not too different than writing

```
a = 0+1
a = 0+1
```